# Non-negative linear regression with xgboost

Tags: r, xgboost

This is my first question here so I'm sorry if it's not properly asked.

I'm playing around with the `xgboost` function in R and I was wondering if there is a simple parameter I could change so my linear regression `objective=reg:linear` has the restriction of only **non-negative** coefficients? I know I can use `nnls` for non-negative least squares regression, but I would prefer some stepwise solution like `xgboost` is offering.
If there is no easy way but a complicated one I would be happy to hear that, too. I read there is an option to build custom objective functions. So maybe you could change the `reg:linear` function at some point to get the **non-negativity**?

Thank you very much for your advice in advance!

Comment: This is easily done with a transformation. log your target variable and it changes from positive to unbounded. Exponentiate your results to get them back on the original scale.

Comment: Thank you! I really didn't think about changing my data. I will try this.

Comment: It's a very flexible technique. Anything bounded on only one side can be transformed (flipped if necessary and then shifted) to be positive, and then logged. Anything bounded on two sides can be scaled and shifted to be in [0,1] and then you can use a logistic transformation.

Comment: At the moment all my data ist bounded in [0, 1020000]. There are quite some 0's in my explanatory variable and my independent variables, too. So just using the log function in R doesn't do the trick I would think?

Comment: Perturb the zeros up by just a little bit. Add `1e-6` to them or something.

Comment: Thank you very much! That really helps a lot.